# Echoing css-link makes code work. Why?

Tags: php, css, echo

i just stumbled across the weirdest thing that has ever happened to me in coding. I defined a variable `$csslink = '../styles/global.css';` in php and call it in HTML via

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $csslink; ?>' />
```

but it doesn't work. The page is displayed without the styles specified in `global.css`.

Now when I put

```
echo $csslink;
```

after the definition of `$csslink` and before the html, it works.
What the hell?

**edit**

It's only the case in Firefox (Chrome/IE work without the `echo`) also it doesn't matter what I echo, if it's `echo "xxx";` it still works.

**edit2**

I changed it to the long `<?php` tag, doesn't make a difference though.

Comment: do you have enabled the ASP tags?

Comment: You need to get rid of the asp-like tags, as they are going to be [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_alternative_php_tags) in the next major php version

Comment: `<?php echo $csslink; ?>` is considered to be the best practice. I wouldn't use `<%` and `<?=` in any case.

Comment: `<?=` should be fine if you are running php 5.4+. But `<?` is not fine and will never be.

Comment: I still wouldn't use any shorthand echos or shorthand opening tags. It's only a few extra characters to type, come on... and then it would be compatible with whatever PHP version you happen to use.

Comment: i tried <?php echo $csslink; ?>, doesn't make a difference

Comment: The main reason why short tags were considered "bad" for a while but are now back in "good graces" is mainly because of a lot of people using short tags in templates since they are arguably cleaner.

Comment: could it be that css defines a border but theres no room for it on the page? only when echoing something above the html theres room for it?

Comment: "It's only the case in firefox" can we see the resulting post-processed HTML source code?

Comment: Well I think using short-tags is perfectly fine. Its insane for security reasons to run a totally outdated PHP version so who cares about that? If its really the case that old applications still have to work and wont be updated to newer PHP, well it cannot be helped but the advantage in a template is huge. I totally prefer to say <?=$var?> instead of <?php echo $var; ?> This shorthand is especially nice in connection with ternary operator!

Comment: Please don't edit your post to reflect suggested answers.

Comment: what do you mean post-processed? the output on the page?

Comment: @Dyon Yes. The output you get for that line particularly when you click "View source" of the resulting webpage.

Comment: Also I agree with @Steini, so does [php-fig using the PSR-1 coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../styles/global.css' />  and when i click on  ../styles/global.css  it opens the correct css file

Comment: @Dyon Then PHP is not the problem. You've somehow created a cross-browser incompatibility. With the same code, PHP returns the same thing for every browser every time unless there are explicit conditionals on the user agent. Perhaps use the accepted HTML format of using double quotes `"` instead of `'` i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/global.css" />` but in terms of the "echo not working" or anything similar to it - we cannot find a problem here.

Comment: "" or '' doesn't make a difference

Comment: There still isn't an issue in the scope of your problem. `echo` and its variants work as expected. You are looking for a problem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<?=$csslink?>`. I guess `<% %>` is ASP syntax, not PHP.

If it still doesn't work, ensure, that ALLOW_SHORT_TAGS in php.ini is on.

Answer (score 0):

they are ASP tags.

Try with PHP short open tags:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?=$csslink?>' />
```

If this is also not working try with PHP normal tags:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $csslink; ?>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $csslink; ?>' />
```